# How to Read Contents of an Audio File to a string

Tags: c#, file, encoding, streamwriter

I'm working on an app that needs to write the contents of a music file to StreamWriter which is used to create a copy of the file. My first attempt resulted in a file that couldn't be played. Comparing the two file's contents in Notepad++ showed a lot of differences between the two files, namely the copied file having a lot of box characters.

I thought this might be a problem with encoding, so I wrote a quick test that loops through all the System.Text.Encoding default values, for both reading and writing, to see what that would do. For my test mp3 file, it resulted in three versions that are playable, but distorted, while the others wouldn't play at all. I also tested this with a wav file. There were three playable files again, but different encoding combinations.

Here's my code for generating the different encoded files:

```
        private string FolderPath => @"D:\Encoding Test";

        private string FileName => "Test Song.mp3";

        private string FilePath => Path.Combine(FolderPath, FileName);

        public void Encode()
        {
            var encodings = new[] { Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF7, Encoding.UTF32, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode };

            foreach (var readerEncoding in encodings)
            {
                foreach (var writerEncoding in encodings)
                {
                    ChangeEncoding(readerEncoding, writerEncoding);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ChangeEncoding(Encoding readerEncoding, Encoding writerEncoding)
        {
            var contents = ReadFile(readerEncoding);
            WriteToNewFile(readerEncoding, writerEncoding, contents);
        }

        private string ReadFile(Encoding encoding)
        {
            using var fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
            using var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, encoding);

            var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

            return contents;
        }

        private void WriteToNewFile(Encoding readerEncoding, Encoding writerEncoding, string contents)
        {
            var newName = GetNewFileName(readerEncoding, writerEncoding);
            var newFilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, newName);

            using var fileStream = new FileStream(newFilePath, FileMode.Create);
            using var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream, writerEncoding);

            writer.Write(contents);
        }

        private string GetNewFileName(Encoding readerEncoding, Encoding writerEncoding)
        {
            var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);

            var newName = $"{fileNameWithoutExtension}-{readerEncoding.EncodingName} to {writerEncoding.EncodingName}{extension}";
            return newName;
        }
```

How can I read the contents of an mp3 or wav file into a StreamWriter and get it to save to a file correctly?

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string at all? Why not copy it using a 2nd filestream and leave it as bytes?

Comment: My end goal is to have the application save to the Music folder on my Android phone. I have some code for saving to _a_ music folder (not the right one) based on [this blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-xamarin-android-mediastore-part-1-keith-beatty). I don't think I can leave it as bytes with this method.

Comment: I completely fail to understand why you are reinventing the wheel, `File.Copy` exists for a reason. Even if you did want to do this yourself, you absolutely should leave it as bytes. Audio files don't have string encodings, and attempting to do so is going to make you lose information even if you use UTF-16

Comment: My previous comment addresses why I couldn't use `File.Copy`. I was not aware that `BinaryWriter` existed to write bytes to a `Stream` directly. Using that I was able to get my file to save correctly.  
  
So I guess the answer to my question is that you can't read it to a string. @Charlieface if you'd like to leave that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, you would need `BinaryWriter`. But judging by the code above, you could indeed do `File.Copy(FilePath, newFilePath);` which seems to essentially do the same thing: you are anyway writing to a new filepath

Comment: The code above was an attempt an isolating the problem I was having, namely saving the file contents into a `StreamWriter`. My actual use case requires that I write to a `Stream` which is obtained through the Android SDK. Using `File.Copy` in that environment would result in saving to application specific memory and that is not what I wanted. Not to mention that the file I'm "copying" is coming from the internet, not the device. Including this information would have complicated the original question, so I left it out.